# Convert ISO-8859-7 to utf-8 without bom from linux terminal

Tags: utf-8, opencart, iconv

Hi I feel like I tried everything now and I wonder if you can help me out.

I want to import some products to my Opencart store using Total Import, and I have this file right here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9K8gCgLRq9zLTQ3c0NaSHdERGs .
For some reason when I convert it locally with Notepad++ to UTF-8-BOM Total Import recognises the language and works perfectly, but I need this to be done automatically and I cannot find how to convert it with "iconv" or "recode" commands for some reason.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: How did you get that file? That file contains the byte value `0xAE` which is [invalid in ISO-8859-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7), the encoding is more likely [Windows-1253](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1253), so the xml charset declaration is wrong.

Comment: This came from my supplier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iconv --from ISO-8859-7 --to UTF8 file.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that, It seems that the issue was causing a special character "®" thank you!